# Wordpress: get previous_post_link() based on custom field value

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I have a custom post type. Pages of this custom post type are displayed via a special template. in this template i use `previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link()` to create links to previous/next posts of this custom post type.

Since I currently only want to show a few of these custom-post-type pages to my users, I created a custom field called `release` with a boolean `true/false` value to indicate if these posts should be shown.

Obviously, the `previous/next_post_link()` functions should also be aware of that. However, they are not currently. That means they also link to pages where the custom field `released` is set to `false`. How can I tell these functions to only use pages where a custom field (`released`) has a specific value (`true`).

Update: I know that the solution is to apply some filters to the default functions and to somehow adapt the SQL query which is used to retrieve previous/next posts. However I do not know how to put together the puzzle pieces (where/how to apply the filters and how to adapt the SQL)

This may be related to this question, however I dont really know what to do: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8823/how-to-order-adjacent-posts-prev-next-by-custom-field-value

This seems also to be related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96670/custom-post-type-navigation-on-custom-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couldn't get it to work even though I know how it SHOULD work: `addFilter()` for `get_{$adjacent}_post_join` and `get_{$adjacent}_post_where` with custom SQL query code..

However, this plugin did the trick for me: http://www.ambrosite.com/plugins/next-previous-post-link-plus-for-wordpress

I used the `in_same_meta` key.

Comment: meanwhile, the plugin mentioned is already 6 years old, still doing his job, impressed